# How should you write a long lived species?

Tags: fiction

If a humanoid species lived for thousands of years, how should they be written? With age and experience comes wisdom and knowledge. Would there psychology be different? Would they be more patient and resistant to change with advancement becoming stagnant?

Comment: Write them however you want. What do you want to accomplish by using these characters? What role should they play on your story? Their behaviour can extrapolate from there.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question, and good options to handle it depend heavily on your specific story. In general, we avoid "brainstorming" questions, as they work poorly in the Q&A format. Try your own ideas first, and see if you run into any troubles fleshing those out :)

Answer (score 4):

Knowledge and Wisdom are two very different things, and one does not mean the other. To steal shamelessly from the Miles Kington quote:

> *Knowledge is knowing a tomato is a fruit. Wisdom is not putting it in a fruit salad*

As Sara Costa points out, cultural impact will have a major role in how the individual acts, especially towards others. The setting itself will also play a major role.

There are a number of considerations:

- Is your long-lived race the only long-lived one?
- Do they interact with other short-lived races?
- Are they a fading civilization, holding desperately to the last fires of glory? Or are they a relatively young empire - full of lust for glory and achievement? Are they living in their golden age or desperately trying to recapture it?
- What is there birthrate like? Usually the longer-lived races have a low birth-rate (or a dwindling one) to balance out
- What age is considered mature? Old? How do they age (i.e. is infancy/adolescence human like and the "mature" by about 18/20? Or is it 50-60 before they are no longer considered a "child" and 150 before they are considered an "adult"? Do they age slowly, or do the age normally until a certain point and then slow down?)
- What is the technology level? Level of advancement - both for themselves, the world at large, and in comparison to others?
- Are they "protectionist" or "xenophobic" - often the long lived races are seen as xenophobic, because as a race they must be. Dwindling numbers, loss of lands, betrayal by younger races etc. Long lives means long memories, and grudges can carry through generations.

There are numerous other things to look at as well, which is solely dependent on your story and your setting, but there are some good examples out there to use for inspiration, both traditionally literary (e.g. Tolkien) but also tabletop and rpg sources as well.

One that I've found that has always resonated well and done well to explain things (well, up until a couple of years ago anyway) was the Warhammer Fantasy Elves. If you can find the old background material and army books for High Elves, Dark Elves and Wood Elves, you get a very, very in-depth look at what the society looks like, and how they act individually. The Eldar in Warhammer 40,000 also are a good example of long-lived races and how they act.

Essentially, both the Elves and Eldar can live for thousands of years. They both have glorious histories and are in decline as a civilization - war, disaster etc have made them a fraction of what they were.

They are given to introspection, and also arrogance because they know they are better than the younger "upstart" races - faster, smarter etc. The are also given to melancholy and ennui, as there are very stark reminders of what they've lost.

As far as experience goes, they tend to focus on one thing at a time - perfecting it and then moving on. The Eldar have different Paths that they follow - various Aspects of War (so a particular fighting style), Command (their leaders and generals), Artisan (artists, creators etc) and so on. The Elves are similar - they will focus on one thing at a time, so an elf may spend 150 years mastering painting, or the bow before moving on. Those who focus solely on single thing (such as the Swordmasters) are unmatched in their mastery.

Their long lives means that elf merchant you are dealing with may be an excellent artist, an excellent swordsmen, an adept spell caster, fluent in every language (including several no-longer used), a musician able to move you to tears and so much more.

Answer (score 3):

You should develop those long-lived characters as you would any other.

Think about people that come to be in their 80s or 90s. Some are wiser and more patient than younger ones. Some are bitter and impatient. Many feel like the world is moving on faster and they've been stranded (because it's more difficult for most older brains to catch up with novelties).

The point is that one's experiences help to determine how wise or bitter you'll turn out to be. So look at the long lives of your characters: what kind of experiences did they have? Did those experiences lead them to lose faith in society and the future?

Besides that, think about their culture. Is it a culture that values experience or novelty? Is it conservative or is eager to find a weakness in the knowledge of the past while hunting for the more valid, freshly acquired knowledge?

Older or younger, your characters are all the same deep inside: human (or human-like).

Answer (score 1):

They're your characters. You decide. They might become more patient and wise, like you suggest, or they might become tired and grumpy and less tolerant. They might become sad, living with pains and regrets and losses. They might collect loved ones or lose loved ones.

I'd say these people would reflect the author's view of what life is like.